# In python, how do I start a process while also then exiting my current program?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Suppose I have executable A, which checks to see if it can be updated when it runs. If it can be updated, I would like executable B ("updater.exe") to run and perform the updates, but in order for the updater B to function, I need A to exit.

I tried this code, but A stays open while B is running, and that is resulting in errors:

```
subprocess.Popen("start cmd /C updater.exe", shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True, creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)
exit(0)
```

Of note: this is for a program that primarily is used on Windows 10 if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your python script would have to terminate for updater.exe to run, but assuming there is some interaction between A and the thing that B updates, say D, I would suggest something like this:

One option:

Try to isolate the parts which interact with the program needing an update in a single module or class. Whether this makes sense depends on your program architecture among other factors.

Another option:

Write a 'watchdog' script C, which periodically runs script A (e.g. using the windows task scheduler). Script A then returns its exit code to script C, which communicates whether an update can be performed using e.g. `subprocess.check_output()`, script A now runs, and script B can be run if C needs to update D.

```
# script C
import subprocess
from time import sleep 
# ^^ time.sleep may be a bit of a blunt hammer for this purpose;
# there are libraries which allow more advanced control/scheduling
# (like the stdlib's 'sched', or one could use windows task Scheduler. 
# On UNIX you could use CRON jobs, but on UNIX OSes one probably 
# wouldn't have this problem in the first place.


update_check_interval: int = 86400
watchdog_path = Path("C:/full/path/to/scriptB.py")
updater_path = Path("C:/full/path/to/updater.exe")

exit_codes_can_update = {
    1: True,
    0: False,
}
# ^^ This seems superfluous, but it could be confusing that usually 
# processes return 0 if successful, which in this case means
# 'not-updateable', or the other way around depending
# on what you make script A return.

while True:

    status = subprocess.check_output(
                 ['python',
                  f'{"str(watchdog_path)"}'])

    if exit_codes_can_update[status]:

        subprocess.call(
            ['start',
             f'"{updater_path}"'],
             stdin=None,
             stdout=None,
             stderr=None,
             creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS) 

    # ^^ double quotes w/ f-strings in the paths are there
    # case there are spaces in the path, although I am quite
    # uncertain that this is necessary.

    sleep(update_check_interval)
```

I don't think you need the `shell=True` parameter.

There are probably errors in here; I can't easily test on Windows right now. Furthermore, I doubt this is the preferred way to do this, but it may give you one possible approach.